# How do i handle secrets in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

What is the common practice here? There seems to be no tools provided by `gcloud`. I'm deploying functions from local machine for now, so I can hardcode secrets, but this seems inappropriate. Also, what about CI/CD? I would need to pass secrets as environment variables in this case. Is this even possible atm?

Comment: No, this is not possible unfortunately. Pretty crazy that such a simple feature is not possible with a product put out by a company like Google, but we just have to make do. Hopefully they'll add this functionality once Cloud Functions comes out of beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since making my comment, I've found a relatively simple way to do this - provide a config `.json` file. Here's an example I hacked together based on their Slack function example:

**config.json** file in the same directory as **index.js**:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

**index.js**

```
const config = require('./config.json');

exports.envTest = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(config.foo);
};
```

When you deploy the function and go to the URL, you should get the response `bar`.

**Pros and cons:**

Pros:

1. Easy to set up and configure right in your IDE
2. Config file can be put into `.gitignore` to ensure your secrets don't end up the repo
3. File itself can be stored in a secure location and only given to individual responsible for deploying the functions

Cons:

1. Clunky in comparison to proper secret management
2. Requires attention to ensure the file doesn't fall into the wrong hands
3. **File can be read in plaintext in the Google Cloud console by looking at the function source**

On the whole, it's a far cry from a real secrets management system, but it's workable enough to hold me over until this feature eventually makes it into the Cloud Functions core.

Comment: If the secrets can just viewed in plain text in the cloud console or in the storage bucket where the code is stored. I don't know if this solution is really providing much value. Might as well hardcode the secret in your repo.

Comment: I disagree, you can strictly control who has access to the cloud console. It's the difference between your entire developer base having access to the secrets, and one guy who is designated to run the GCP portal. No, it's not ideal, but ANYTHING is better than hardcoding secrets.

Comment: fair. yea it is better then hardcoding in source control.

Comment: If your functions are for private use, then you could encrypt the file and pass a decryption key as a header or post body. This along with an embedded key of some sort could be combined to decrypt the file and reveal the secrets.

However if your function is called publically by others then it is more difficult to make this work.

This results in satisfying encryption at rest, and security through obfuscation to some extent. 
Again this is not optimal but imo even better than the other solutions.
p.s. hey dan

Comment: You can also use `firebase functions:config:set api_key="whatever"`, see here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env  Trust your developers. If a hacker gets access to your GCP account, they can steal all the secrets anyway.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/quickstart) for this. Follow the instructions on the link to add a secret.

The only GOTCHA I found is that by default the service account doesn't have read-access to the secrets, you've got to manually grant permissions, like so:

[image: Add secret permissions]

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Cloud Key Management Service(KMS)](https://cloud.google.com/kms).
Don't push pure secrets to Cloud Functions with files or environment variables.

One solution is followings:

1. Create key on Cloud KMS
2. Encrypt secret file with that key
3. Upload encrypted secret file to Google Cloud Storage(GCS) (Accessible by specified user)
4. In Cloud Function Execution, get uploaded secret file from GCS, decrypt, and use it

[Ref] [Secret management using the Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management#secret_management_using_the_google_cloud_platform)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the above answer?
An brief article might help everyone.

Comment: I would suggest using this approach but with Environment Variables instead of GCS. This would make it much easier to access and update the secret, but just as secure since you're still using KMS to encrypt/decrypt.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021-08-25, the preferred way to handle secrets in Google Cloud Functions is with the [native Secret Manager integration](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets). This integration enables you to mount secrets in Google Secret Manager via environment variables or the filesystem.

1. Create or migrate your secret to Google Secret Manager (there's a generous always-free tier):

   ```
   $ gcloud secrets create "my-secret" --replication-policy="automatic" --data=...
   ```
2. Update your Cloud Function deployment to reference the secret:

   As an environment variable:

   ```
   $ gcloud beta functions deploy "my-function" --set-secrets "MY_SECRET=my-secret:latest"
   ```

   Via the filesystem:

   ```
   $ gcloud beta functions deploy "my-function" --set-secrets "/path/to/my/secret=my-secret:latest"
   ```

To practice the principle of least privilege, it's recommended that each Cloud Function be deployed as a dedicated service account. You need to grant that service account access to the secrets your application requires.

Comment: This is nice, but it seems it is not yet supported by the terraform resource google_cloudfunctions_function. Any plans on this ?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this and mounting the secrets as volumes, but even after printing literally the entire directory tree in __dirname nothing seems to be coming up. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I've added a secret with `--update-secrets` in the `deploy` command, but `MY_SECRET` ends up being this long string: `projects/1234567890/secrets/my-secret:latest`, which is not what I want. I just want the variable to refer to the string `my-secret`.