# Google Cloud Functions: How to Use Security Certificates in Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Function that calls an API. This call requires .pem and .key security certificates which I have uploaded to a storage bucket. I am trying to use them in the Cloud Function. It seems like a simple task, but none of the code I've tried or found online works. This is what I currently have:

```
def receive_request(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json:
        source_bucket = storage.get_bucket('bucket_name')
        pem_file = source_bucket.get_blob(request_json.get('pem'))
        key_file = source_bucket.get_blob(request_json.get('key'))
        url = 'https://api_url/api/v2/acls'
        response = requests.get(url, cert=(pem_file,key_file ))
```

Where the JSON is just:

```
{"pem":"file_name.pem","key":"file_name.key"}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not Blob
```

When I tried to use the GS path ("gs://bucket_name/file_name.key") GCP does not deploy the function. How can I properly structure the import of these two files?

Comment: You are passing the object `google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob` to `requests.get`. You need to read the blob and pass that data. Look at `pem_file_data = pem_file.download_as_string()`

Comment: You can find similar threads in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959284/passing-sensitive-information-to-cloud-functions) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667422/how-do-i-handle-secrets-in-google-cloud-functions/49214452).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i handle secrets in Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667422/how-do-i-handle-secrets-in-google-cloud-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Secret Manager to store your cert? It would probably make more sense than storing them on cloud storage.

See https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs for more information.

Comment: I've tried this but I haven't managed to pull the file in to the function. I'm struggling to find examples of using secret files in functions - do you have any examples or additional resource recommendations?